# Are there online variants to "Path of Glory"? WH40K

Tags: house-rules, warhammer-40k

I've been watching a handful of this extended campaign type for a while now and I just saw a video where someone created an Ork war-band by using a dice-roll sheet prepared from custom rules. **Can anyone tell me where to find such custom rules, or how to create a dice-roll sheet for a specific faction?** I find Path to Glory more in-depth than the core game modes, but I only have regular space marines.

Answer (score 1):

**Mini War Gaming** published a series of battle reports of Chaos vs. Orks.

You can find them [here](http://www.miniwargaming.com/show/path-to-glory-orks-chaos) (half of them are free to view, the rest need a subscription).

Then, a user named **Boff89** got inspired and shared [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B58upxPJ3ho2QUZLTzFhSmEzOEk/view?pref=2&pli=1) on [their forum](http://www.miniwargaming.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=117112). The introduction to the rules is signed by "**Eric PB**".

While these aren't the same exact rules used in Mini War Gameing's videos (I think), they look like what you're looking for.

I guess you can also try to ask MWG on their forum to share these rules, or make your own version using the videos and the PDF as a starting point...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll try to find a space marine variant through them